# All subfolders and files (from Downloads) are inaccessible : Permission could not be determined

Tags: command-line, permissions

In my home dir. `Downloads/` I tried to revert the systematic addition of the executable bit `+x` on all files when copied from a NTFS drive (in Xenial 16.04)ls -l SA.

I found this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/234647/how-to-remove-executable-bit-recursively-from-files-not-directories) on `superuser.com` and performed

```
$ chmod -R -x *
```

from `~/Downloads`

However right after that, all subfolders and files therein appeared greyed out in Nemo / Nautilus. For example

```
$ ls -l SABnzbd/
ls: cannot access 'SABnzbd/complete': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'SABnzbd/incomplete': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? complete
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? incomplete
```

When I right click `Properties` on the greyed out folder `incomplete` I get this:

[image]

I have tired to assign new permissions to no avail:

```
$ sudo chown elise:elise SABnzbd/complete
$ sudo chmod 775 SABnzbd/incomplete
$ sudo chmod a+x SABnzbd/complete
```

I cannot `cd` to any sub-directory

```
$ cd SABnzbd/
bash: cd: SABnzbd/: Permission denied
```

As I always get the question marks and no access to anything past the first level.

I cannot access the inodes ? Nothing has been deleted however usual ways to set permission are not working ... How to revert this ?

Some have posted this question before however no one has yet answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing execution permission on your directories.

The `x` permission has a special meaning on directories, you need it to retrieve informations about its contained files and subdirectories.

To restore the `x` permission for all users on directories recrsively  inside the current directory, the command below will help you:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Comment: Simpler: `chmod -R +X .`.  With capital `X`,  this turns on execute only for subdirectories.  (If a file already has execute permission for someone, this also extends it to all users; for this case, though, that would appear not to be a problem.)

Comment: OK. I believe your solution using a find on directories will work fine.
I did find a solution right before posting my question : It was to re-assign `permission 775` to all directories directly under `~/Downloads` with
`$ sudo chmod 775 [directory]`
And to remove the +x bit on all files I used
`$ find . -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;`

Comment: Modifying the files has nothing to do with it, but setting all the directory permissions to 755 manually has the same effect as my command.

Answer (score 0):

May be try with root to change permission to your home directory:

```
sudo su
chown -R my-user:my-user /home/my-user
chmod -R 775 /home/my-user
```