ls -la gives strange output
What could be the reason for this?


You have to share more information about the file system. For example: df -T ..

It doesn't seem to be the case here, perhaps Artur Meinild is right, however for others stumbling upon this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/828428/all-subfolders-and-files-from-downloads-are-inaccessible-permission-could-no

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use a [code block] to format it

Does this answer your question? All subfolders and files (from Downloads) are inaccessible : Permission could not be determined

To me, this looks like a volume mounted with a "Filesystem in Userspace" (FUSE), which is only visible to the user who mounted it. Other users will see the exact output you get.
An example of a FUSE mount would be sshfs, which I use where I mount it as root. And I get the exact same message when I try to list the contents as a non-root user: (I've shortened the output to only the beginning and end)
am@xb:/var/log$ ls -la
ls: cannot access 'xo': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'xv': Permission denied
total 5244
drwxrwxr-x  18 root       syslog             4096 Apr 21 04:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 root       root               4096 May  8  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root       root                883 Apr 18 06:54 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root       root               4010 Mar 28 06:19 alternatives.log.1
...
...
-rw-rw-r--   1 root       utmp            1020672 Apr 22 09:31 wtmp
-rw-rw-r--   1 root       utmp            1057920 Jul 13  2023 wtmp.1
d??????????  ? ?          ?                     ?            ? xo
d??????????  ? ?          ?                     ?            ? xv
ls: cannot access 'xo': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'xv': Permission denied
am@xb:/var/log$ 


I see this on both NFS and SMB mounts, where something has interrupted the network connectivity, but the mounting daemon has not recovered gracefully.
You can umount the share and remount it, assuming the network blip has cleared then it should work immediately.
